# FormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll() with external references in Excel cells returns RuntimeException using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

For the past couple of days, this has been driving me crazy.

Please consider the two Excel files:
[a.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4dah.jpg) and [b.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmBMh.jpg)

Here are the codes that are supposed to evaluate cells in **a.xlsx** including the external reference to **b.xlsx**.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Abid\\Desktop\\a.xlsx");
            FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Abid\\Desktop\\b.xlsx");

            XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(file2);

            FormulaEvaluator evaluator1 = workbook1.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator2 = workbook2.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            Map<String, FormulaEvaluator> workbooks = new HashMap<String, FormulaEvaluator>();

            workbooks.put("a.xlsx", evaluator1);
            workbooks.put("b.xlsx", evaluator2);

            evaluator1.setupReferencedWorkbooks(workbooks);
            evaluator1.evaluateAll();

            file1.close();
            file2.close();

            workbook1.close();
            workbook2.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately this is what I get upon execution:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve external workbook name 'b.xlsx'. Workbook environment has not been set up.
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:113)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.getRef3DEval(OperationEvaluationContext.java:313)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getEvalForPtg(WorkbookEvaluator.java:634)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:505)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:205)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:189)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:117)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:346)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:337)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:105)
    at Test.main(Test.java:28)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CollaboratingWorkbooksEnvironment$WorkbookNotFoundException: Could not resolve external workbook name 'b.xlsx'. Workbook environment has not been set up.
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CollaboratingWorkbooksEnvironment.getWorkbookEvaluator(CollaboratingWorkbooksEnvironment.java:195)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getOtherWorkbookEvaluator(WorkbookEvaluator.java:156)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:111)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with apache-poi, but I see in the error output "Could not resolve external workbook name 'b.xlsx'. Workbook environment has not been set up."

Comment: I did set up the workbook environment.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Good luck.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I am using the latest stable release, Apache POI 3.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Apache POI 3.15 beta 3 or newer, or a nightly build / build from svn / build from git on / after 2016-08-04. As [covered in the Apache POI changelog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.15-beta3), this was an XSSF-specific bug that has been subsequently fixed

Using a build/release with the fix in it, a call to `evaluateAll()` on a `XSSFFormulaEvaluator` will now use any referenced workbooks already setup, just as HSSF did all along.

Answer (score 2):

It will work without issues with `HSSF` (*.xls).

But apache poi is a mess. So [XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll()](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_14_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java?revision=1732982&view=markup#l104) will simply call `HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(_book);`. But [HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(Workbook wb)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_14_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java?revision=1732982&view=markup#l335) will create a **new** `FormulaEvaluator` which is not involved within the environment.

Instead it should call [HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(Workbook wb, FormulaEvaluator evaluator)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_14_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java?revision=1732982&view=markup#l339) and hand over the `FormulaEvaluator` which **is** involved within the environment already. But this method is `private`.

Fortunately it is not as much big and independent. So we can have this method within our code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class TestEvaluateExtRef {

     private static void evaluateAllFormulaCells(Workbook wb, FormulaEvaluator evaluator) {
         for(int i=0; i<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
         Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);

             for(Row r : sheet) {
                 for (Cell c : r) {
                     if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                         evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Workbook workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("a.xlsx"));
            Workbook workbook2 = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("b.xlsx"));

            FormulaEvaluator evaluator1 = workbook1.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator2 = workbook2.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            Map<String, FormulaEvaluator> workbooks = new HashMap<String, FormulaEvaluator>();

            workbooks.put("a.xlsx", evaluator1);
            workbooks.put("b.xlsx", evaluator2);

            workbook2.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue(new java.util.Random().nextDouble());

            evaluator1.setupReferencedWorkbooks(workbooks);

            //evaluator1.evaluateAll();
            evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook1, evaluator1);

            System.out.println(workbook1.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0));
            System.out.println(workbook1.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());

            workbook1.close();
            workbook2.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference between HSSF and XSSF for this. If you're able to write a small junit test that shows the problem, and can upload it to the POI bugzilla, I'm happy to take a look!

Comment: @Gagravarr: My explanations and my sample code here shows pretty clear where the problem is. With `evaluator1.evaluateAll();` it fails. With `evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook1, evaluator1);` it works. Having `a.xls` and `b.xls` it works also with `evaluator1.evaluateAll();`.